# Does $R=\rho l/A$ apply to an electrolyte solution?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-current, electrical-resistance

I'm planning a physics experiment on how the distance between two electrodes in an electrolyte solution affects the current in a circuit, but I'm having trouble determining the expected result.

Comment: Yes, you can apply $R=\rho\frac lA$ but note that $l$ is the distance between the electrodes and $A$ is the surface area of the electrodes. $\rho$ as always, is the _resistivity_.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly do such experiments.
But bear in mind: For the relation $R=\rho l/A$
to be true, the current flow needs to be homogenous
between the electrodes and neglectable outside this region.
There are some alternative ways to achieve this.

1. Choose a cuboid vessel with the electrodes occupying
   the entire faces at the edges.
   [image]
2. Choose a geometry with the electrodes much larger
   than the distance between them, meaning $A \gg l^2$.
   [image]

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that electrolysis is occurring when a current is passed through the electrolyte and so you should use an ac power supply and ac meters to take the readings.
Choosing the material of the electrodes to reduce the effects electrolysis might be necessary.

A frequency between 1 to 3 kHz as is used in commercial conductivity meters will perhaps be best but 50 or 60 Hz will do if you do not have easy access to the higher frequency apparatus.
This is to reduce ant effect due to electrolysis.
Measurement using a [Wheatstone bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wheatstone_bridge) with an ac supply will probably be more accurate and necessitate only one ac meter/oscilloscope/**headphones**/etc to detect the null point.

To reduce "edge effects" the plates that you use should be of the same size as the cross section of the rectangular trough.

Keep the temperature of the solution as constant as possible and the plates which are immersed in the water as parallel to one another as possible.